# Django Rest Framework PUT request returns 500, but updates data

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm fairly new to Django REST framework and I've tried to write an API for my mobile application. I'm facing an issue where a PUT request works fine (updates data) apart from the fact it returns response 500 (Internal Server Error). Some guidance towards resolving this would be much appreciated.

**views.py**:

```
@csrf_exempt
def category_instance(request, pk):
    """
    Returns Category instance
    """
    try:
        cat = Category.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse("Error: category does not exist", status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = CategorySerializer(cat, many=False)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = CategorySerializer(cat, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, 200)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        cat.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)

    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

**models.py:**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('category/<int:pk>/', views.category_instance)
]
```

I've tried to look for similar issues that other people may have had, but I was unable to construct a solution to my problem.

---

**Traceback**:

```
Internal Server Error: /category/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34,
 in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in
_get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in
_get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, i
n wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\android_tm_api\api\views.py", line 146, in category_instance
    serializer = CategorySerializer(cat, data=request.data)
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Comment: Please add your server error log

Comment: Why are you not using https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveupdatedestroyapiview ?

Comment: I've included a traceback to the post. To be honest I was following a django-rest-framework tutorial on setting up an API and was not aware of the generic-views.

Comment: Can you also add which all middleware you're using ?

Comment: Checking that the request had a data object before referencing it would solve the issue. You might be making two calls - one with data and one without.

Comment: I'm testing using Postman app to send requests to the API, which then retrieves data from a PostgreSQL db

Comment: The error is raised before `serializer.save`, so nothing should get saved in this request. In any case, the error message explains what's wrong. `request` does not have a `data` attribute. Maybe you mean `request.body`? If you use django-rest-framework's built in generic views or modelviewsets, all this error handling is already implemented. The drf docs contain tutorials and examples of how to use the generic views.

Comment: @HåkenLid Thank you. I resolved the issue by replacing the views with generic class-based views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by replacing the views with [generic class-based views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/) instead.

Comment: I'm still not completely sure as I've had an API in the past which seemed to work fine with it.